# Connection String for SQL database not working in VBA

Tags: vba

I am using the below line to use as connection string from VBA to SQL database:

`cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Asset_Output;Data Source=GA-SQL"`

It gives me below error:

[image]

I am trying to run the query to get all table names in the database using this connection.

Updating the integrated security to 'True' gives the below error:

[image]

Complete Code:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim iCols As Integer
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


SQLStr = " Use Asset_Output  " & _
         " select name, modify_date from sys.tables order by  modify_date desc"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Asset_Output;Data Source=GA-SQL"

rs.Open SQLStr, cn

With Worksheets("Input").Range("E2:Z50000")
    .ClearContents
    Worksheets("Input").Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End With
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: What is `GA-SQL`? Is it returned by `Environ` as a full name,  path included? There a full name of the data base to be accessed must be provided.

Comment: GA-SQL is the Server Name. It's what is used in the SQL management Studio.

Comment: I supposed that, but if you want to access it from a computer, do you simple type `GA-SQL`? If this is its name, I am thinking at something as `\\GA-SQL`... Can you map it on your computer? I never worked with such a server, so my questions may look strange... I often used SQL but extracting something from a data base, and I needed the full path to the respective data base. Being an Access file, even Excel. I am thinking in this way only by association. I could see nobody tried to give a piece of advice, at least...

Comment: Yes, it works like that in SQL Server. It was working in VBA as well until they switched the servers to 'SQLNCLI11'.
Is there any reference that needs to be activated?

Comment: `Provider=SQLNCLI11` as you are using. But don't you need `Server=myServerAddress` or credential to connect at the respective server (`Uid=yourUsername;Pwd=yourPassword;`)?

Comment: Integrated Security takes cares of it. it's like passing windows Authentication.

Comment: See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/ - all of those examples have a "Server" component to the connection string.